# Nginx to Cloudfront Dist

Tags: nginx, amazon-cloudfront

Strange issue with nginx > cloudfront dist > S3 bucket to serve up a file in the browser, this works hitting the cloudfront dist directly but not when trying to go via nginx, just wondering if anyone has experienced the same issue ? What's even stranger, is it was working via nginx briefly, but wondering if it was being cached for a while, I can't wrap my head around it for some reason.

Nginx config below

```
location /cdn/ {
          # ssl
          proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
          proxy_ssl_server_name on;
 
          # header
          proxy_set_header HOST $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 
 
          proxy_pass https://redacted.cloudfront.net/cdn/aa/;
      }
```

Hitting this directly

```
https://redacted.cloudfront.net/cdn/aa/somefile.js
```

Works absolutely fine, however, when going via nginx, i just keep getting an access denied. I can see from the nginx logs, it is going through, and i can see the 403 from the cloudfront logs as well.

nginx url = https://redacted.co.uk/cdn/somefile.js - always throws a 403.

It did work briefly, not sure if it was a false positive or what.

Cloudfront Dist has path pattern of /cdn/* and within the S3 bucket, has an object "cdn" followed by three other objects within it called "aa" "bb" and "cc" for example. Within those three objects is a .js file i want served within the browser

I keep trying different things with nginx and nothing seems to work, just wondered if anyone has come across this before ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found out weirdly, that if the alternative domain in the cloudfront dist is different to the nginx domain it won't work, very strange indeed but have resolved the issue.